# How can i disable the Team project mode in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio and during installation i think i somehow ticked the Team Project checkbox. Now i'm unable to create a normal ASP.NET website in any way. I would be very grateful if someone tells how to fix this thing. Also i have uninstalled and installed seven times. But no luck. Thank you.

Comment: No description of an error.  No mention of a VS version.  This is a poorly documented question.  You can monkey with Tools + Options + Source Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I  have understood You right. You try to change default templates in IDE for Web developers.

In Visual studio you can easily change the profile of the IDE by going to Tools -> Import Export Settings. This brings up Import Export Windows Wizard. Follow the simple Wizard (which also allows to save you the current settings  for future use) and select the new profile setting (based on the kind of project you are working on) and you are ready to work with new profile.

I assume You need to choose "Web development".